# How is the two phases-commit different than transactions in the relational databases

Tags: mongodb, transactions, database

The Mongo website says that the [two-phase commit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/) is `transaction-like` only. 
But they demonstrate an example of transferring money between accounts which is a very typical example when showing about how transactions work in the relational databases.

If the two-phase commit is performing correctly, isn't it just the same as the traditional transaction? 
How are they really different from each other?

Thanks!

Comment: well for one a transaction has different dynamics since it is actually supprted within the database itself, the DB holds the lock for the duration of the transaction even if others are waiting, MongoDB will not do this. Also transactions are normally atomic, MongoDBs 2 phase commit actually is not

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for the steps described in your link to fail somewhere in the middle, causing transactions to be applied to one document only. In this case a [recovery process](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/#recovering-from-failure-scenarios) must be initiated by the application. In a transactional relational database there is no application initiated recovery process. Either the whole transaction works or it doesn't. (That is, unless you use distributed transactions, which do require 2 phase commit).

Comment: The last part isn't entirely true it depends on when the database commits. Quite a few databases have a commit set to 5 mins for transactions which means that you can have a rollback scenario at times. Even though transactions are normally atomic they don't have to be